# material UI core multiple select

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-material-ui-form-validator

I am new to react and material ui core. The problem I am having with the document is that it uses a function to initialize constants like so https://material-ui.com/components/selects/

but I use react with class extending components like so

export class Departments extends Component {

So it gives an invalid hook call for the constants.

Can somebody help me give a code example of how to use multiple select in material ui core. using class extends component.

Here is the code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    maxWidth: 300
  },
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 500
  },
  chips: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));

export class Departments extends Component {
  handleChangeField = (event, key, values1) => {
    this.setState({ values1 });
  };

  selectionRenderer = values1 => {
    // change the default comma separated rendering
    return <span style={{ color: "#ff4081" }}>{values1.join("; ")}</span>;
  };

  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };
  back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  };

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;

    const {
      values: {
        Title,
        Details,
        What,
        Why,
        How,
        Status,
        Cost,
        Benefits,
        Kpi_Before,
        Kpi_After,
        UOM_Before,
        UOM_After,
        Base_After,
        Target_After,
        dateTime_After,
        Base_Before,
        Target_Before,
        Time,
        dateTime,
        departments
      }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className={useStyles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Toolbar>
                <Typography
                  gutterBottom
                  align="center"
                  style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  Select Departments
                </Typography>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <FormControl style={{ width: "80%" }} size="small"></FormControl>

          <br />
          <br />
          <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="left"
            alignItems="left"
            style={{ marginLeft: "5%" }}
          >
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              onClick={this.continue}
              style={{ marginLeft: "10%" }}
              style={styles.button}
            >
              Continue
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="default"
              size="small"
              style={styles.button}
              onClick={this.back}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
    secondary: purple
  },
  status: {
    danger: "orange"
  }
});

const styles = {
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    verticalAlign: "bottom"
  }
};

export default Departments;
```

Comment: instaed of putting whole code can you please share in which code in which you have facing issue.

Comment: better to use hooks instead of class if you writing component code from scratch, if you have existing code with class component then better to create new component for select using hooks as given it doc and use it in existing code.